# Microsoft SQL - "Invalid column name" after deleting column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am using Azure SQL in Microsoft SQL Management studio. I firstly renamed a column called `ssma$rowid` to `ssmarowid`, then I deleted this column using

`ALTER TABLE "myCoolTable" DROP COLUMN "ssmarowid";`

SQL management studio prompted me that the deletion was successful, but now that I try to run any `UPDATE` commands on my table in different columns, I get this error message:

`Invalid column name 'ssma$rowid'.`

If I try to edit a cell without scripting, by right-clicking my table, then `Edit top 200`, I get this error message:

`The data in row xxx was not committed.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Invalid column name 'ssma$rowid'
Invalid column name 'ssma$rowid'
Invalid column name 'ssma$rowid'`

`Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s)`

The column `ssma$rowid` does not appear in my table at all when I run a `SELECT` statement, and if I explicitly try to pull the column `ssma$rowid` or `ssmarowid` SQL tells me that they don't exist.

It appears that my column has been lost in the ether somewhere, where can I start searching to find my rogue column?

Comment: I would start by checking if the table has triggers that might be referencing the old column

Comment: I ran a delete for both `ssma$rowid` and `ssmarowid` for good measure and the console returns now that neither exist, despite the errors I'm facing @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Ok thanks @eugenioy I will check that

Comment: If things are still referencing the old column, of course you're going to get errors. You should clean anything up that referenced it. If you had SSMS open with the edit screen on that table, you probably need to close and re-open it so that it doesn't try and update a non-existent column.

Comment: The suggestion by @eugenioy looks good; check for triggers which might still reference the old columns.

Comment: Use sql search(red gate), try searching for the column name that throws error.

Comment: Does the below posts help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493744/invalid-column-name-when-published-on-azure 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260487/sql-server-reports-invalid-column-name-but-the-column-is-present-and-the-quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the `ALTER TABLE` states the column between brackets like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [myCoolTable] DROP COLUMN [ssmarowid];
```